# Change class variable reference within the class

Tags: python

I want to be able to change the reference of a variable within the class Test

```
class Test():
    def change(self, Other_Class):
        self.__class__ = Other_Class.__class__
        self = Other
class Other():
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def one(self):
        print('foo')

a = Test()
b = Other()
b.set_data([1,2,3])
a.change(b)
a.data

AttributeError: 'Other' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How can I change the reference to a to be what ever variable I pass through to Test().change

I would like this to work for builtin datatypes as well, but I get a different error for that.

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: In what use case / scenario would you ever want to set `self = <something else>` ?

Comment: The Python data model doesn't work like that.

Comment: `self` is a parameter, and parameters are just local variables. And rebinding local variables doesn't have any effect on anything outside of the function. In particular, it has no effect on any other variables (or list elements, or attributes of other objects, etc.) that were bound to the same value.

Comment: I have a promise based class and I want to when the promise gets resolved for that class to become the returned value, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: No, and having objects suddenly switch themselves out for other objects from underneath you wouldn't be as convenient as you're thinking anyway. How would you know whether to treat an object as a promise or a result? What would happen if a promise switched itself out for some other object while you were trying to create a promise chain or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Test.change`, that `self` is a parameter, and parameters are just local variables.

And rebinding local variables doesn't have any effect on anything outside of the function.

In particular, it has no effect on any other variables (or list elements, or attributes of other objects, etc.), like the global `a`, that were also bound to the same value. They remain names for that same value.

It's not even clear what you're *trying* to do here. You change the type of `a` into the type of `b`, and that works. But what else do you want to do?

Do you want to change `a` into the object `b`, with the same identity? If so, you don't need any methods for that; that's what `a = b` means. Or do you want to be a distinct instance, but share an instance `__dict__`? Or to copy all of `b`'s attributes into `a`? Shallow or deep? Should any extra attributes `a` had lying around be removed as well? Do you only care about attributes stored in the `__dict__`, or do you need, e.g., `__slots__` to work?

Anyway, something that *might* be reasonable, for some strange use case, is this:

```
def change(self, other):
    inherited = dict(inspect.getmembers(self.__class__))
    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(self):
        if name not in inherited and not name.startswith('__'):
            delattr(self, name)
    self.__class__ = other.__class__
    inherited = dict(inspect.getmembers(other.__class__))
    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(other):
        if name not in inherited and not name.startswith('__'):
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

Whether that's useful for *your* use case, I have no idea. But maybe it gives you an idea of the kinds of things you can actually do with the Python data model.