# Python promise class turn to the resolved value

Tags: python

I have a promise-based class similar to this:

```
class Promise():
    def res(self, returned):
        #set the value of the instance to the returned value

promise = Promise()
promise.res("Returned Value")
print(promise)
>>>"Returned Value"
type(promise)
>>>str
```

When I resolve the promise, I want the instance of the class to be the resolved value (str, dict, Class...). How can I do this?

Comment: Objects magically changing type sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: however one that is very very possible in python ... beware though down this path lies madness

Comment: Everything we said on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218536/change-class-variable-reference-within-the-class) still applies. Knowing that the object represents a promise doesn't really change things.

Comment: didn't think I was explained myself well enough

Comment: Joran, what are these secrets???

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you wanted but you can use __call__ magic function.

Comment: I saw an article a few years back in python weekly that did this exact thing ... here is a simillar article that i found that might help point you in the right direction https://pythontips.com/2013/09/20/all-about-the-metaclasses-in-python/ ... but i dont think this is a very good idea

Comment: This is a really unpythonic idea. But if you insist on doing it, the closest you can get is a (near-)universal proxy object, which passes as much as possible (including dunder methods like `__str__`) through to its proxied object. Then a `Promise` starts off having its own attributes, but once resolved, it stops doing that and starts proxying to whatever it was resolved to. It's not exactly what you asked for, but it's as close as you can get in Python.

Comment: But meanwhile, what do you want to happen if you try to, e.g., call a method on the promise before it's been fulfilled? In languages built around transparent promises, like ProML, what that does is automatically blocks the coroutine (a la `await` in Python) until the promise is fulfilled. In dataflow languages, that's even how you create coroutines in the first place. That's a very cool language feature, but it's hard to imagine how you even remotely could fit that into Python.

Comment: So you end up wanting something like `Promise.wait` or `Promise.__await__` or `Promise.__call__` or whatever for other reasons—at which point that can just return the resolved value, instead of returning `self`, so there's no reason for a proxy in the first place. In other words, exactly how deferreds, futures, and promises work in concurrent.futures, asyncio, Twisted, JavaScript Promises/A, etc.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are a few rare cases where changing `__class__` is… well, maybe not a great idea, but at least the least bad idea. The most (in)famous one is doing the equivalent of 3.7's `ModuleType.__getattr__` in Python 3.0-3.6.